# MVC Controller Method Parameter Always Null

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

My javascript function is calling my MVC 4 controller, but the parameter is always null. This seems to be a common problem, and I've tried a few things I've researched, but nothing is working. Any idea why it's always null?

My javascript GetEntries() function correctly creates an alert that shows the value:

```
function GetEntries(firstLetter) {
    alert(firstLetter);
    $.post('/Home/GetEntries',
           firstLetter,
           EntriesReceived());
}
```

My controller method breakpoint gets hit:

```
public void GetEntries(string firstLetter)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(firstLetter);
}
```

However, firstLetter is always null. I'm not sure what to do.

**Failed attempts:**

**I tried posting using JSON.stringify.**

```
function GetEntries(firstLetter) {
    alert(firstLetter);
    var firstLetterAsJson = JSON.stringify(firstLetter);
    $.post('/Home/GetEntries',
           { jsonData: firstLetterAsJson },
            EntriesReceived());
}
```

**I tried adding the HttpPost attribute to my controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetEntries(string firstLetter)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(firstLetter);
}
```

**I tried changing the parameter name to "id" to match my route mapping:**

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetEntries(string id)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(id);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work

```
function GetEntries(firstLetter) {
    $.post('/Home/GetEntries', { firstLetter: firstLetter }, EntriesReceived);
}
```

Also notice how the `EntriesReceived` callback is passed to the `$.post` function as third argument. In your code you seem to be calling the function (`EntriesReceived()`) instead of passing it as callback. Here I assume that this function is defined like this:

```
function EntriesReceived(result) {
    // handle the result of the AJAX call here
}
```

And if you want to send it as a JSON request you should use the $.ajax method which allows you to specify the proper request content type:

```
function GetEntries(firstLetter) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetEntries',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ firstLetter: firstLetter }),
        success: function(result) {
            // handle the result of the AJAX call here
        }
    });
}
```

Another problem I see with your controller action is that you defined it as `void`. In ASP.NET MVC the common established convention is that all controller actions must return instances of the `ActionResult` class. But if you don't want to return anything to the client then use the specific ActionResult for this case - EmptyResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetEntries(string firstLetter)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(firstLetter);
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: That worked. I really appreciate the quick help. In my research of the problem, I didn't see anywhere where it said to do `{ firstLetter: firstLetter }`. Maybe I just missed it. Thank you!

Comment: And, yes, there is an EntriesReceived() function defined like you stated. And I agree about not returning void. I just haven't gotten that far yet. Great tips. Your thorough and accurate answer are really appreciated. You've helped me more than you know over the past few months. Thanks again.